# Share video to Instagram feed from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I've been trying to create a sharing experience for our app where Instagram launches giving these two options:

[image]

Facebook has a pretty [lean documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed) about it. I tried all the possible permutations using the UIDocumentInteractionController. I tried using as `uti` `com.instagram.photo` and `com.instagram.video` with the `ig` extension but I keep getting the standard sharing popover instead of launching Instagram directly. Tried also `com.instagram.exclusivegram` with `igo` but that seems to be supposed to trigger the standard popover anyway.

Latest code:

```
func shareVideo(_ filePath: String) {
  let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
  if(hasInstagram()){
    let newURL = url.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension("ig")
    do {
      try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: url, to: newURL)
    } catch { print(error) }

    let dic = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: newURL)
    dic.uti = "com.instagram.photo"
    dic.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Has the exact same problem. I did manage to share a photo like this, but I can't find support for video. you too?

Comment: Yes, but I've seen apps that do that. How frustrating having to deal with so poor documentation.

Comment: True. Do you have Skype? Maybe we can tackle this together

Comment: @RoiMulia if you have the same problem, perhaps you can upvote the question.

Comment: Just did it now, sorry didn't pay attention to the up vote

Comment: @RoiMulia any luck?

Comment: This seems quite relevant: https://blog.horizon.camera/post/102273431070/video-share-objc-ios-instagram I was hoping I didn't have to save the asset to the camera roll though.

Comment: Same..Saving is too much of a work for a simple share. I'll get I'll just give up in IG share lol. Is sharing to IG is mandatory on your side?

Comment: @RoiMulia it is. How can developers support suck so much?

Comment: @RoiMulia feel free to chip in: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/290939481761146/

Comment: Any updates on that? I got stuck at that hopeless documentation too.

Comment: @dobranoc there is a way, let me answer to my question later today...

Comment: @dobranoc added answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to get to the screen illustrated above is to save first the video in the library and then use the undocumented hook `instagram://library` passing the asset `localIdentifier`. Don't forget to add `instagram` query scheme in the `info.plist`.

```swift
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL("instagram://app") { // has Instagram
    let url = URL(string: "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + videoLocalIdentifier)

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I found that it also works if you change the url to `"instagram://library?AssetPath="`. Did you figure out if it's possible to also pass a caption string?

Comment: I found it more stable with `LocalIdentifier`. I doubt that would be possible. Hopefully I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I asked Facebook Developer Support when do they plan to provide usable documentation. They answered they don't. (not in the near future)

Comment: @dobranoc same here. They have other priorities, like exploiting kids.

Answer (score 15):

Try this. I am currently sharing my last saved video by this:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject {
    let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
    let u = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
    let url = NSURL(string: u)!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: u)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        
        let urlStr = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8"
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After a day of research and trying this was the answer that helped me the most!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)postMedia:(NSString *)media Type:(BOOL)isVideo {

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:LS(@"Downloading...")];

    //download the file in a seperate thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:media];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( urlData ) {

            NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:isVideo?@"instagramShare.mp4":@"instagramShare.jpg"];
            NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if (![urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
                    [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:LS(@"Failed. Please try again.")];
                    return;
                }

                // Check authorization status.
                [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^( PHAuthorizationStatus status ) {
                    if ( status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ) {

                        // Save the movie file to the photo library and cleanup.
                        [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                            // In iOS 9 and later, it's possible to move the file into the photo library without duplicating the file data.
                            // This avoids using double the disk space during save, which can make a difference on devices with limited free disk space.                            
                            PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *options = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];
                            options.shouldMoveFile = YES;
                            PHAssetCreationRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset];
                            if (isVideo)
                                [changeRequest addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypeVideo fileURL:outputFileURL options:options];
                            else
                                [changeRequest addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto fileURL:outputFileURL options:options];

                        } completionHandler:^( BOOL success, NSError *error ) {

                            if ( success ) {

                                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                                PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
                                fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
                                PHFetchResult *fetchResult;
                                if (isVideo)
                                    fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:fetchOptions];
                                else
                                    fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
                                PHObject *lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject;
                                if (lastAsset != nil) {
                                    NSString *localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier;
                                    NSString *u = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=%@", localIdentifier];
                                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
                                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
                                        } else {

                                            NSString *urlStr = @"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8";
                                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:LS(@"Failed. Please try again.")];
                            }
                        }];
                    }                   
                }];
            });
        }
        else {
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:LS(@"Failed. Please try again.")];
        }
    });
}
```