# How to post image to instagram Feed Directly in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

is there any way to share image to instagram feed directly. I can Only Share image using default share functionality i m using swift 5 and xcode 11

Comment: Instagram API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

Comment: read these 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios . 2. https://github.com/hiren443/InstagramShareiOS .  3. https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit

Comment: Check this answer, in which last saved video is shared. You can use the same for image by replacing .video with .image. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019593/10842413

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to post images/video to the Instagram app directly. Instead you can pass the image/video to the app and follow the process of manually posting to Instagram normally, there is another catch as well you cannot pass the title (caption) either you would have to copy the text to clipboard and on the final process of posting you can paste that text from clipboard.